# Not loading the codeigniter model

Tags: codeigniter

I have a model product_model which I am loading in controller function delete. when I run the project I got the error "Call to a member function delete_merchant_products() on a non-object in /home/danish/www/hbs/application/controllers/admin.php on line 173". I am confuse why is this happening. Below is cotroller function code. model name is product_model.

```
function delete(){
    // deleting the merchant data.
            $this -> load -> model('merchant_model');

            $output = $this -> merchant_model -> get_records();

            $list['merchants'] = $output;

            $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_merchant_title','Merchant Title','required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):

                $this->load->view('admin/merchant_delete_view',$list);
            else:
                $merchant_title = $this->input->post('txt_merchant_title');

                                $merchant_title = str_replace("-", " ", $merchant_title);

                $temp_path = realpath('../hbs/merchants');

                $dir = $temp_path .'/'.$merchant_title .'/';

                system("rm -rf ".escapeshellarg($dir));

                 $this->load->model('product_model');
                $this->porduct_model->delete_merchant_products($merchant_title);//error.
                $this->merchant_model->delete($merchant_title);
                echo "Delete successfully";
            endif;  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on this line:

```
$this->porduct_model->delete_merchant_products($merchant_title);//error.
```

porduct instead of product.

Comment: Please elaborate typo? I did'nt understand.